# Get initial value of UIPickerView swift

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to save a UIPickerView value, and I want to be able to get the correct value if the user never touches the UIPickerView.

Below will set pickerChoice to the value I want if the user moves the picker, but I can't find anything that tells me how to get the initial value of the picker if it is never touched.

```
class DonateVC: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var pickerDonate: UIPickerView!
    var toPass:String!
    var success:NSInteger = 0
    let pickerData = ["PAWS Chicago", "Anti-Cruelty Shelter", "Almost Home Foundation"]
    var pickerChoice:NSString!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerDonate.dataSource = self
        pickerDonate.delegate = self
        //pickerDonate.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    }
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return pickerData[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        pickerChoice = pickerData[row]
    }
```

Comment: Initialize `pickerChoice` with `pickerData[0]` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: But when I view the page, the middle option is actually selected. So pickerData[1] would be correct here. I'll be dynamically inserting the list, so I can't just assume pickerData[1] is correct either.

Comment: In `viewDidLoad`, initialize the picker view's selected index with 0 (or which ever value you want as the initial value). Initialize `pickerChoice` with the same value.

Comment: Yea I tried that and was getting an error. If I Un comment the line with selectRow my program throws an error on that line. I'm new to iOS and Swift but the error made no sense and wasn't returning much on Google so I decided to ask the question this way instead. Do you see something wrong with the commented line in viewDidLoad

Comment: Update your question with details about the error. And there is no reason to animate the selection in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is what you need.  If you have not selected anything in the picker yet this should still work to return the current value that would be displayed in the picker.

```
pickerChoice = pickerData[pickerDonate.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
```

So pickerData is your data array for the picker and pickerDonate is your UIPicker.